# How I do "check" dynamically generated checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble "checking" dynamically generated checkboxes.

The checkboxes are inserted into the DOM using Jquery load()

```js
$("#result").load('checkboxes.php',data);
```

I now want to "check" the checkboxes based on their values

```js
for (var i = 0; i < $length; i++) 
{
            $v=$array[i];
            $("input:checkbox[value="+$v+"]").attr( "checked", true );
}
```

However, It won't work with the newly inserted elements.

I know how to work with dynamically created elements. ie $(document).on() except there is no event here. All I'm doing is running a function once JQuery load() executes. There's no click or change events etc.

I'm stumped. Halp!

Comment: Please share checkbox.php code, maybe you set check state for each in the checkbox.php instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery load() has an optional callback function. I put the code that checks the boxes into a function and passed it to load()

```js
$("#result").load('checkboxes.php',data,function(){do_checkboxes()});
```